# Revert a single revision from a merge commit in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, git-svn, tortoisemerge

Following a merge commit under SVN (Merge commit with more than 10 revisions), I want to revert a single revision from the merge commit.

Is it possible to do this manipulation on SVN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can revert the commit on the main branche, the one you used as source in your merge, then you merge the commit of the revert with your destination branche.